# npx runs older version of gist on github

Tags: node.js, gist, npx

I created gist list to run script with npx.
Expected behaviour: after updating script npx should run new version.
My result: first installed version is running.

What I need to do to clear a cache?

Comment: I have the same issue using GitHub repo as source. Adding @latest doesn't do anything, neither does a version tag.